# GroupBy and Shift based on the values of a column

Tags: python, pandas

Let's suppose that I have the following dataset:

```
Stock_id    Week    Stock_value
1   1   2
1   2   4
1   4   7
1   5   1
2   3   8
2   4   6
2   5   5
2   6   3
```

I want to shift the values of the `Stock_value` column but only for consecutive weeks.

This should give the following output:

```
Stock_id    Week    Stock_value
1   1   NA
1   2   2
1   4   NA
1   5   7
2   3   NA
2   4   8
2   5   6
2   6   5
```

So for example at store 1 the Stock_value of week 2 should not be shifted over to week 4 (since I want one week shift for now).

How can I do this easily?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC using `week` with its `diff` create another group key

```
df.groupby([df.Stock_id,df.Week.diff().ne(1).cumsum()]).Stock_value.shift()
Out[157]: 
0    NaN
1    2.0
2    NaN
3    7.0
4    NaN
5    8.0
6    6.0
7    5.0
Name: Stock_value, dtype: float64
#df['Stock_value2']=    df.groupby([df.Stock_id,df.Week.diff().ne(1).cumsum()]).Stock_value.shift()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer (upvote). This should work I think. I would like a little bit to understand why to use the .cumsum() .